# Stop all makefile actions when C++ hits error call in unix

Tags: c++, unix, error-handling, makefile

I have a makefile that does multiple things, including calling a bash file and making a C++ file. In the bash file I have the code:

```
echo "${variable}: Error" 1>&2
exit 1
```

Which prints error text then exits the batch file and the makefile, stopping it. I want to do the same thing with the C++ code. I can throw an error and stop the C++ code at wherever the error was thrown, but I can't seem to figure out a way to make it stop the makefile as well. Is there a way to do this? Thanks for the help.

Edit: Mentioned in a comment below, but the makefile both compiles the code then runs it in the next section so it would be best to be able to break out of the makefile both on a compile error and a run error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're talking about Makefiles, I'm assuming that you want to stop the Makefile during the *compilation* of the C++ program (and not the execution of the resulting program).

If that's the case, use the `#error` preprocessor directive.

```
 #if !defined(FOO) && defined(BAR)
 #error "BAR requires FOO."
 #endif
```

Reference:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/cpp/Diagnostics.html

Comment: Actually now that I think about it being able to do both would be good. The makefile both compiles the program then runs it in the next step. So being able to break during a compile error is good, but breaking during a execution would be good as well, if you happen to know how to do that. Either way thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Just make your program `exit(1)`. `make` expects successful child processes to return 0, and unsuccessful ones to return 1.

Comment: Both exit(1) and just a return 1 don't seem to stop the makefile. The execution of the C++ program stops, but the makefile still runs the next commands its set to run (in this case some mysql commands).

Answer (score 2):

To signify an error status during runtime of a C++-program, you can do the following:

Printing an error to the error stream is done with `std::cerr`:

```
std::cerr << "This will not do!\n";
```

Passing an error status that make will understand is done by returning a non-zero value from `main`:

```
int main() {
    // Your program
    if (error_condition) {
        std::cerr << "This will not do!\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You can also terminate the program, optionally with an error status, from anywhere in the program using the `exit` function from `#include <cstdlib>`:

```
#include <cstdlib>

void not_main() {
    std::exit(1); // Non-zero value here indicates error status to make
}

int main() {
    not_main();
}
```